# Assignment of read only location error when assigning value of pointer to other pointer?

Tags: c

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    const char *str="geeksforgeeks";
    for(i=1;str[i];i++)
    {
        for(j=0;str[j];j++)
        {
            if(str[j]>str[j+1])
            {
                temp=str[j];
                str[j]=str[j+1];
                str[j+1]=temp;
            }       
         }
    }
    for(i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
```

Do not understand why this error occur when i try to write `str[j]=str[j+1]`?
I'm doing something wrong here please do tell me?

Comment: Because it is declared  `const`.

Comment: It won't work even without `const`, as it is pointing to a read-only string literal.

Comment: yes this is what i'm trying to say that it is also not working inspite of using it without const keyword

Comment: _undefined behaviour_ - again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `str` as `const char *`, so the types of `str[j]` and `str[j+1]` are `const char`, meaning they can't be assigned to.

Beyond that, however, attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

To make your code work, change the declaration of `str` to

```
char str[]="geeksforgeeks";
```

This will declare `str` as an *array* of `char` initialized with the contents of the string `"geeksforgeeks"`; you can manipulate the contents of this array to your heart's content.

Comment: if i donot use const keyword then only a warning showed up but rest of the code is fine, inspite of this i cant get the desired output but it should word? shouln't it?

Comment: @vinay *Never* rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. can i sort the string using bubble method without calculating string's length?

Comment: @vinay You have asked this question before. So seek for the answer there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. haha, u knew that :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. she is my twin sister actually we are working on same problem given us by DAD :)

Comment: @vinay Anyway, you can reuse it

Comment: @Vinay: just removing the `const` isn't enough - attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to undefined behavior.  It may work, it may crash, it may do something else.  Always treat string literals as though they were immutable, whether the implementation does so or not.

Comment: @JohnBode okay i got it